# Remove whitespace from spaced-out word?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pcre

Assume the following string:

```
hello world, h e l l o! hi. I am happy to see you!
```

Is there a way to remove whitespace in the spaced out word, like so?:

```
hello world, hello! hi. I am happy to see you!
```

I tried `[^ ]+(\s)` but the capture group matches all spaces. thank you.

Comment: Was it spaced out with extra space characters?  Or by positioning each character separately?  Kerning?

Comment: Could there be more than one extra space between letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One regex approach might be:

```js
var input = "hello world, h e l l o! hi. I am happy to see you!";
var output = input.replace(/(?<=\b\w)\s+(?=\w\b)/g, "");
console.log(output);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern, which targets whitespace situated in between two standalone single word characters on both sides:

```regex
(?<=\b\w)  assert that what precedes is a single character
\s+        match one or more whitespace characters
(?=\w\b)   assert that what follows is a single character
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have tagged pcre, another option could be:

```
(?:\b\w\b|\G(?!^))\K\h(?=\w\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `\b\w\b` Match a single word char between word boundaries
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\K\h` Forget what is matches so far, and match a single horizontal whitespace char
- `(?=\w\b)` Positive lookahead, assert a single word char followed by a wordboundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8votEZ/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

---

Another option could be matching at least 2 chars in a sequence of single word chars, and in the replacement remove the space.

Note that `\s` could also match a newline.

```js
const regex = /\b\w(?: \w)+\b/g
const str = "hello world, h e l l o! hi. I am happy to see you!";
let res = str.replace(regex, m => m.replace(/ /g, ''));
console.log(res);
```